# How can i filter a data when i type more than 3 characters

Tags: angular, object, filter

Hey I'm trying to create a search bar, when i type more than 3 characters it display only filtered `lastname` of the table, (the condition is empty)

here the **HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput id="search-field" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
</mat-form-field>
<a [routerLink]='["/doctors/new"]' class="doctors-list-newDoctor-button">
  <button mat-raised-button id="doctors-list-newDoctor-button">
    <i class="material-icons">
      add
    </i>
  </button>
</a>
<div>

  <table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="this.displayedDoctors" id="doctors-list-table" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header id="doctors- 
        list-lastName-header">lastName</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let doctor" class="doctor-lastName">
        {{doctor.lastName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef id="doctors-list-firstName- 
        header">firstName</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let doctor" class="doctor-firstName">
        {{doctor.firstName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="format">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef id="doctors-list-format- 
            header">format</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let doctor" class="doctor-inami">
        {{doctor.format}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="inami">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef id="doctors-list-inami- 
       header">inami</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let doctor" class="doctor-format">
        {{doctor.inami}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="DoctorsListHeaders"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: DoctorsListHeaders;" (click)="OpenDoctor(row)"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

here the **model**

```
export interface Doctor {
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
  format: string;
  inami: string;
  _id: string;
}

export const EMPTY_DOCTOR: Doctor = {
  lastName: null,
  firstName: null,
  format: null,
  inami: null,
  _id: null
}
```

here the **typescript**

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.filterSearch = filterValue.toLowerCase();

  this.doctorsService.getAll({ lastName: this.filterSearch, inami: this.filterSearch }).subscribe((doctors: Doctor[]) => {
    //this.dataDoctors = doctors;
    this.displayedDoctors.data = this.dataDoctors;
    if (this.filterSearch.length >= 3) {


    }
    if (this.tableSort) {
      this.sortData(this.tableSort);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: so what is not working here?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i create a condition that show data when i type more than 3 characters on the filter bar

Comment: Please provide `html` code.

Comment: @M.Ela Okey, what data do you want to show? Is it `displayedDoctors.data`?

Comment: this.dataDoctors

Comment: @M.Ela Alright. But let's say the user enters less than 3 characters, do you still want `getAll()` to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filter pipe to achive your objective.

Follow [ngx-filter-pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filter-pipe) and make changes in your code accordingly.
Using pipe you can directly filter the data, when you type in the text filed. You can customise the functionality as per your need.(start searching after 3 chars)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you an exact answer with that amount of information, but from what I can infer, you are probably trying to show and hide a `<div>` containing some data, and that is dependent on the length of `filterSearch`.

This is what I suggest:

On your component.ts, we add another boolean property call `showData`, which will be assigned true or false based on the length of the search input.

```
showData: boolean = false;
.
.
.

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {

  this.filterSearch = filterValue.toLowerCase();

  this.doctorsService.getAll({
    lastName: this.filterSearch,
    inami: this.filterSearch
  }).subscribe((doctors: Doctor[]) => {

    this.dataDoctors = doctors;

    if (this.filterSearch.length >= 3) {
      this.showData = true;
    } else {
      this.showData = false;
    }
    if (this.tableSort) {
      this.sortData(this.tableSort);
    }
  });
}
```

And on your component.html, add the `ngIf` directive that will show or hide that data based on the `showData` boolean condition

```
<div *ngIf="showData">
<!-- data from dataDoctors -->
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you check the length before calling an API?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I know, I have thought of it. But I didn't want to make too many changes to the original code since that is not the main focus of the question. And I was awaiting confirmation from the OP if he would rather me add that length check before or after the API request.